# BOOST async_send_to causes memory leak (1.71)

Tags: c++, boost, asio

[image]

Calling sendSync is fine, Calling sendAsync causes a rising heap.
Is there anybody who knows what could be the reason and how to solve it ?

```
void sendAsync(const std::string& message)
{   
    socket.async_send_to(
        boost::asio::buffer(message), remote_endpoint,
        [this](boost::system::error_code /*ec*/, std::size_t /*bytes_sent*/)
        {
        });
}

void sendSync(const std::string& message) 
{
    boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
    socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message), remote_endpoint, 0,   ignored_error);
}


for(;;)
{
    TeleItems.SentCounter++;
    printf("Sent Telegramm : %u \n",TeleItems.SentCounter);
    sender.sendAsync( "Hi this is a telegramm" );
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
}
```

Comment: This might be unrelated to the memory leak, but in `sendAsync` you will have a dangling reference to the local parameter `message` through the non-owning buffer when it is read from at a later time. You need to ensure that `message` stays alive until the handler is called. Otherwise, you have Undefined Behavior and an apparent memory leak could be just a manifestation thereof

Comment: Thanks, I also tried it without parameters like socket.async_send_to(
        boost::asio::buffer("HI"), ... which did not work as well.

Comment: You cannot start multiple async write operation at the same time on one instance of socket. You have to wait before starting new write operation until previous one is over.

Comment: OK - thanks a lot for the Infos. Is clear now :-)